# jquery autocomplete with getJson do multiple request at a time

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-autocomplete

Here's my code :

```
options = { 
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.getJSON('@Url.RouteUrl("Search")', { prefixText: request.term, count : 10 }, function (retour) {

                response( retour);


            });
         }

    };
    a = $('#test').autocomplete(options);
```

If i'm searching for test , when i begin to write the autocomplete does a request for t, te, tes and finally test...

The "test" request finish first so the autocomplete show the good result but 2 sec later ith show the result for "tes"

Is there a way to abort the other request when i'm writing ?

Thanks

Comment: You can see this link 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution (thanks calixto) :

```
 if(xhr)
            {
                //kill the request
                xhr.abort();
            }

            xhr = $.getJSON('@Url.RouteUrl("Search")', { prefixText: request.term, count : 10 }, function (retour) {

                response( retour);


            });
```